# In angular 8/9, which way is the right way to add date type in interface for data by using material table?

Tags: angular, date

I am using material table in the beginning in the interface i declared the dates as a string however i realised that i cant use filter to compare dates therefore i wanted to know what is the best way to solve this problem

Comment: Moment is also good options many featur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [moment](https://momentjs.com/):

```sh
npm install moment
```

In your interface, you can use the moment type:

```js
export interface Data {
   created_at: moment.Moment;
}
```

Then you could use it to compare/filter your dates in your datasource filterPredicate:

```js
this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (data, filter) => {
    if(data && data.created_at) {
        return data.created_at.isSame(filter);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Check the [Moment query section](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/) to see all the corporations you could use.

---

**UPDATE 07/01/2021:**

Note that Moment is been deprecated in favour of its precedent [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/index.html), so the interface would look like:

```js
import {DateTime} from "luxon";

export interface Data {
   created_at: DateTime;
}
```

And you can filter using:

```js
this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (data, filter) => {
    if(data && data.created_at) {
        return data.created_at.valueOf() === filter;
    }

    return false;
}
```